# Flutter : Voice Command To Open Page

Tags: flutter, dart

I want ask about Voice Command in Flutter . I'm think about voice command to open another Page.
Example : in **HomePage** i have button, if i press the button it's listening the voice, after that if i say "Add Task" it will open TaskPage.

I have search plugin fits with my case and i found [speech recognition](https://pub.dev/packages/speech_recognition).
 But in documentation is convert from voice to text.

It's possible to use this package for my case ? 
Thank's

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that, as I see in this [library's repo](https://github.com/rxlabz/speech_recognition/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart), it returns speech text in `setRecognitionResultHandler` callback

```
void setRecognitionResultHandler(String text) {
  setState(() {
        transcription = text;
  });
 }
```

after that when you receive `onRecognitionComplete` callback you can match speech text and navvigate to **HomePage**,

```
void onRecognitionComplete() {
          if(transcription.toLowerCase().contains('add task'))
           Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/HomePage');
 }
```

Comment: interesting i will try it, but it identify string with space ? 
Example if i say "add task",it will be "add task" or "addtask" ?

Comment: it will be 'add task' but you should consider matching only 1 word either 'add' or 'task' because people pronounce words with different ways in each part of the world so speech recognition may not give expected output every time!

Comment: Hello, i already try the voice command it's work to identify the voice. But it's not Navigate to another page . https://gist.github.com/zgramming/d082581ab9c00f05d97509916d526477